# xml parsing having multiple opening tags

Tags: xml-parsing, ipad-2

I m getting response like this

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Map>
        <URL>
           https://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=ABIL+House,+Ganeshkhind+Road,+Yashwant+nagar,+Pune,+Maharashtra&hl=en&sll=18.539118,73.834095&sspn=0.011169,0.021136&oq=ABIL+House&t=h&hnear=ABIL+House,+2,+Ganeshkhind+Rd,+Yashwant+nagar,+Pune,+Maharashtra+411007&z=16
       </URL>
    </Map>
</NewDataSet>
```

I have to parse url value to show in web view. How to parse xml file having two opening tags, this is my code:

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{ 
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Result"])    { 
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
        currentUser =[[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
    } 
} 

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{ 
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Result"]) { 
        [item setObject:currentUser forKey:@"Result"]; 
        // [item setObject:currentPassword forKey:@"Name"]; 
        [users addObject:[item copy]]; 
    } 
} 

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser )parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{ 
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"Result"])  { 
            [currentUser appendString:string]; 
        } 
    /* if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"Name"]) 
        { 
            [currentPassword appendString:string]; 
    }
    */ 
} 

 - (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
        users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
        NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abilcms.com.sv2.premiumwebserver.com/WebServiceStatus.aspx?UserID=demo@abil.com"];
        xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL]; 
        [xmlParser setDelegate:self]; 
        [xmlParser parse]; 
        NSLog(@"name=%@",currentUser); 
        statuslabel.text= currentUser; 
}
```

Comment: I m using for ipad app. Using objective-c language. I have tried xml parsing 3 methods

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on xml parsing in ios that shows how it is done. http://theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/09/parsing-xml-in-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Here is another tutorial on accessing [multi level XML documents](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html)

But as far as I can see you should just replace "Result" with "URL" if this is the only URL tag in your XML, as fa as I understand NSXMLParser will handle the levels for you in this case. Of course if there is more data in this XML that you need to access you should build it like the example in the second link.

Comment: thanks... i have done with parsing but not getting url value in string

Comment: - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
   
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Result"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentUser =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
      
    }
}

Comment: - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Result"]) {
        [item setObject:currentUser forKey:@"Result"];
        // [item setObject:currentPassword forKey:@"Name"];
        [users addObject:[item copy]];
    }
}

Comment: - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"Result"]) {
        [currentUser appendString:string];
    }
    /* if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"Name"]) {
     [currentPassword appendString:string];
     }*/
}

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{  
    users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abilcms.com.sv2.premiumwebserver.com/WebServiceStatus.aspx?UserID=demo@abil.com"];
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse]; 
     NSLog(@"name=%@",currentUser);
    statuslabel.text= currentUser;
}